# How to make a model aware of its controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator

I am making a Rails application, and i would like to be able use a model object passed to a view to get the URL of some action on this object, like this, for example:

```
link_to object.public_send(attribute),
        { :controller => object.controller_path,
          :action     => :show,
          :id         => object.id }
```

What would be a good way to do this?  Can it be done with a decorator like [Draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper)?  Are there some examples online?

---

**Update.**  I have thought about this and decided that a decorator is not a good place to keep controller information.  It is not decorator's responsibility.  A decorator should only know to render formatted data with markup.  For now i have created a module called `Accessor` where i try to mix models with controller and routing awareness.  I still wonder if there is a better way to do.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need that? Maybe it's something that you can do with [url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for)?

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what i want, but i have already tried it. The big problem with `url_for` is that it relies on [`polymorphic_url`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/537ede912895d421b24acfcbc86daf08f8f22157/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L90) which knows nothing about models and relies on Inflector to guess the controller name. Cannot use custom names. The small problem is that i may want to have different controllers to manage the same model in different situations.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need this for? It seems like you want multiple presenter classes, but it might be overkill depending on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: For now i just want to pass a model, or a "decorated model", to a shared view, and be done with all model-related links in the view.  I was wondering if a decorator was a proper place to add controller awareness (route awareness).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having another instance variable on your view, you can implement this using a very simple class (no need for decorators).

```
class MyRouter
  def initialize(controller, object)
    @controller = controller
    @object     = object
  end

  def url_for(action_name)
    controller.url_for(object, :action => action_name)
  end
end
```

On your controllers:

```
class AController
  def edit
    @router = MyRouter.new(self, object)
    render 'shared_view'
  end
end

class BController
  def edit
    @router = MyRouter.new(self, object)
    render 'shared_view'
  end
end
```

And on your shared view:

```
<%= @router.url_for(:show) # Varies with the controller that rendered the view %>
```

Of course, this assumes that the controller you want as target is the same controller that renders the view, which might not be true. Still, using this pattern you can accommodate a more complex logic that suits your needs (having multiple `Router` classes, for instance), without having to change the view.

Comment: In my case, the target controller depends more on the model class than on the current controller, and there may be several objects passed to the view, and each should direct a link to its own controller.

Comment: How does the target controller vary for each object? It is determined by the controller that renders the shared view? Or there's another criteria?

Comment: The current controller decides which "home" controllers are associated with which model classes. But they will in most cases depend only on the model classes.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a very interesting solution in [Objects on Rails](http://objectsonrails.com/) by Avdi Grimm: [Exhibits for REST](http://objectsonrails.com/#ID-2d96b566-da6d-473f-8bfb-b4022caa4416).  In short, his idea is to apply multiple Ruby's `SimpleDelegator`s as decorators with various functions.